# Why would humans chose to change their appearance

Tags: biology, society, people

Now, the title of the question is somewhat misleading, but to give context. In the far future, humanity has slightly mastered genetic engineering, and many people can now live extremely long lives, however, they also have the added ability to changes their own appearance.

The “appearance” aspect of the description essentially correlates to things such as adding horns or talons or even wings. But this isn’t all that can be added, the appearance of a person can change wildly from looking like this
[image]
To looking like this
[image]

To even looking like this
[image]
Obviously, these examples are pretty extreme, like the second one, but of course their are Major limitations, such as, additions cant make you the size of an elephant or the size of a shrew, additions cant allow you To have multiple eyes on a single limb, additions can’t make you look like a actual tree or shark or ant and more, and so on and so forth.

Of course, their are institutions that allow for a person get use to their new additions, an example of this could be a person getting used to having wings, or a person getting used to having the lower half of a horse, there are also many Laws that restrict certain additions, such as increased intelligence, increased speed, echolocation, and more. Luckily enough, the law does have the necessary tech to enforce said rules.

But the question is: why would the humans of 2120 choose to add such drastic additions

Comment: I guess because, hey, what girl *wòuldn't* want a clawed & skeletal hand sticking out of her hoohah?  That said, this query seems to be just a tad opinion based. Can you fix that?

Comment: I would want to have nice aesthetic horns on my head even now. With a golden blonde mane. Because it would look cool.

Comment: We already have everything from tattoos to subdermal implants for reasons that vary from an expression of art to "because." To the disappointment of parents everywhere, you'd have people using the same reasons for such extreme modifications.

Answer (score 1):

### Superhuman, super-boredom, and no consequences:

Why do people get tattoos, or nipple rings, or any of the (arguably) crazy stuff they do to look different? To add functionality, to look cool or different, and because technology means they suffer few or no consequences. Live long enough and you'll do anything to relieve boredom and stand out from everyone else. Just think of Dr. Steinman from *Bioshock*. Why do perfect when symmetry is the enemy?

If you can add eye stalks that allow you to detect malfunctioning equipment, why not? ultrasonic ears so no one can spy on your conversations with other enhanced persons? Maybe you want to be able to eat constantly and never gain weight without pills. Who knows? But one reason is that some of these modifications allow you to do things normal people can't.

There is a tendency among people to always push body art to the next level. What is there left to do after your hands are claws or your fingers are phalluses? Besides, it's not like you can't go back next week and have it all switched around to something completely different. Goat-centaur is all the rage this week at the fancy parties. Why not? You might get a better job if the fantastical people like you.

And maybe you want to support your favorite political party. After all, why NOT have a donkey or elephant head? Have no visible mouth and it's a statement about suppressing free speech. There are no long-term consequences, because flesh is like clay. You reshape it at will. So experiment! What DOES it feel like to be a woman? A hermaphrodite? Or maybe you want a break from sex and just have it cut off for a while.

Then there's old-fashioned boredom. Life spans are going to explode if you can manipulate flesh like this. Being ordinary is so ORDINARY! Sure, it's awkward to have eight spider legs, but at least it isn't the same thing. Your neighbor copied your extreme body design, and now that look is SO done. How are you going to top it? Well, there's this guy who can...

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, certain people might choose to change their appearance so radically because they want to belong to a group that wants to be distinct from mainstream society.

The group wants to be different to seperate themselves.  Normal humans won't want to look like them, or even be near those who look like them, only those who are sympathetic will want to associate with them or look like them.

These people who want to look different might be terrorists, or 2120's equivalent of goths, or they may be members of a persecuted group, or just fans of some similar-looking celebrity.